# Check if the weekday of a datetime is between 2 datetime values

Tags: .net, datetime, dayofweek

I would like see how others are solving this problem in .Net

**Scenario**: I would like to check *`if the current datetime (Now()) is > Monday 6:00AM and < Friday 10:00PM`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario can be interpreted in two ways:

1.You want to check if current date is between monday and friday, and if current hour is between 6:00 and 21:59. If that's the case, you can use the following function:

```
bool DateIsInValidRange(DateTime date)
{   
    if(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) {
        return false;
    }

    if(date.Hour < 6 || date.Hour >=22) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

2.You want to check a plain date range (that is, 23:00 is ok as long as it is not friday, and 5:00 is ok as long as it is not monday). In that case:

```
bool DateIsInValidRange(DateTime date)
{   
    if(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) {
        return false;
    }

    if(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && date.Hour < 6) {
        return false;
    }

    if(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && date.Hour >= 22) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

For the current time, invoke it as:

```
bool isInValidRange = DateIsInValidRange(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm specifically seeking to check if Now() is BETWEEN (Monday 6am) and (Friday 10pm)

Answer (score 0):

```
   bool CheckDay(DayOfWeek start,DayOfWeek End, DayOfWeek toCheck)
   {
  if (start <=max)
    return toCheck >=start && toCheck<=End;

return toCheck >=start || toCheck <=End
  }
```

Comment: sorry, just thought `SQL` in tags